# django - form.cleaned_data[] for all fields in model

Tags: python, mysql, django, forms

I am using django to digitalise a form. This form is a little bit complex, and there are a lot of fields in it. I was wondering if Django could do form.cleaned_data[] for all fields, in stead of declaring variables like `obj.fieldname = form.cleaned_data['fieldname']` for each field apart.

I tried it with a forloop in the **views.py**, but that won't work

This is the forloop I'm talking about:

```
def get_form_naw(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            for x in Model1():
                formname = x.name
                o = Model1()
                o.formname = form.cleaned_data[formname]
            o.save()
    else:
        form = Form1
    return render(request, 'folder/home.html', context=locals())
```

I'm using a mysql database. My forms are declared like this: 
**forms.py**

```
class Form1(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        exclude = ('id')
```

Comment: You could directly save the form to create the object. Why do you need to create the object field by field?

Comment: Your exclude is missing a trailing comma, i.e. `('id',)`. However, you shouldn't need to exclude the `id` field, because it will not be included by default.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to loop through the fields. You are using a model form, so you should just [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) the form:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save()
    ...
```

If you really need to set fields dynamically, you can use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr).

```
fieldname = 'username'
value = 'my_user'
setattr(obj, fieldname, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the instance of the data before saving like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False) #get instance without saving
    # do your thing
    obj.save() #save into database
```